# Parent function of $\sqrt{x^2 - 4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Does this particular function($\sqrt{x^2 - 4}$) have a parent, such that it can be represented as a translation, compression, rotation, stretching, etc, of the parent graph?

Comment: Consider that this function has a restricted domain [ $ \ x \ge 0 \ $ ] and that its graph is two disjoint curves.  If any of the simple operations you mention are to be used, that would have to be done _non-linearly_.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: The domain rectriction is $|x|\geq 2$.

Comment: Yeah, thanks:  I had a wrong picture in my head of the function, then corrected the description and not the domain.  I also wasn't clear as to what sort of parent function was intended to be transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=\sqrt{x^2-4}$ is the top half of the two branches of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2 = 4$, with standard form $\dfrac{x^2}{2^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{2^2}= 1$.  It could be thought of as a vertical and horizontal stretch by a factor of $2$ from the "parent" hyperbola $x^2-y^2 = 1$.  In that case, the parent function is $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, and your function is $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2-4}$, with $g(x)=2f(x/2)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Start from the curve $y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$. Multiply by $2$. We get 
$2\sqrt{x^2-1}$, which is $\sqrt{4x^2-4}$. Now replace $2x$ by $x$.

So here we can consider $y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ as the mother curve. For some purposes, this has advantages.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it is, don't know why I saw a fraction that wasn't there.